# Pandas fill NaN using prior value corresponding to some other pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very large dataframe that looks like the following:

```
    fraction     id                
0   0.729797       0 
1   0.141084       1 
2   0.226900       2 
3   0.960937       3 
4   0.452835       4 
5   NaN            1 
6   0.352142       2 
7   0.104814       3 
8   0.345633       4 
9   0.498004       1 
10   0.131665       2 
11   NaN            3 
12   0.886092       4 
13   0.839767       1 
14   0.257997       2 
15   0.526350       3
```

Currently I am just filling NaN data with 0s using the following line of code:

```
df.fillna(0,inplace=True)
```

Is there a way to fill all NaN data using the prior "fraction" value using corresponding "id"s?

For example, the row at index #5 has a NaN value for "fraction", and has an "id" value of 1. The prior "fraction" value for id #1 was 0.141084.

Is there a way to replace with this value, and do this operation for the entire dataframe?

Thank You

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fillna (forward fill) on a large dataframe efficiently with groupby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871783/fillna-forward-fill-on-a-large-dataframe-efficiently-with-groupby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform a `groupby` on `'id'` and then forward fill with `ffill`:

```
df['fraction'] = df.groupby('id')['fraction'].ffill()
```

Note that you can do the same process on all columns in your DataFrame at once by omitting the `['fraction']`.  In the case of your example data the output is the same:

```
df = df.groupby('id').ffill()
```

The resulting output:

```
    fraction  id
0   0.729797   0
1   0.141084   1
2   0.226900   2
3   0.960937   3
4   0.452835   4
5   0.141084   1
6   0.352142   2
7   0.104814   3
8   0.345633   4
9   0.498004   1
10  0.131665   2
11  0.104814   3
12  0.886092   4
13  0.839767   1
14  0.257997   2
15  0.526350   3
```

Comment: Awesome! Was tinkering with groupby, but did not think about forward fill. Thank you!