# Faster way to forward-fill and back-fill a groupby

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I want to `ffill` and `bfill` a specific column after a groupby.

My solution works:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    "B": [np.nan, 'f1', 'b1', np.nan, np.nan, 'f2', 'b2', np.nan]
})
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda _: _.ffill().bfill())
```

So this:

```
    A   B
0   1   NaN
1   1   f1
2   1   b1
3   1   NaN
4   2   NaN
5   2   f2
6   2   b2
7   2   NaN
```

Becomes this:

```
    A   B
0   1   f1
1   1   f1
2   1   b1
3   1   b1
4   2   f2
5   2   f2
6   2   b2
7   2   b2
```

Note that the sequences I want to ffill and bfill will always be in this format (`Nan, x, y, Nan`)

While this works, it's extremely slow on large dataframes.

I'm looking for some optimization to make this faster (ideally without resorting to using Dask or multiprocessing), maybe there's a Numpy optimization I can make?

I havn't had a lot of luck looking at other answers, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871783/fillna-forward-fill-on-a-large-dataframe-efficiently-with-groupby) one.

Comment: By "in this format" do you really mean the groups are always 4 rows long with the first and last elements missing, or is it more illustrative, i.e. there will be *some* streak of NaNs (any length), 2 non-null values then some other streak of NaNs? The proposed solutions only work for the very specific first case.

Comment: Thanks for the question; I mean that the groups will always be 4 rows long, and that the outer two values will be NaN, and the middle two will be filled.

Comment: btw, you don't need that lambda, just do `df.groupby('A')['B'].ffill().bfill()`.  I doubt it's significantly faster tho, just simpler.  The groupby itself already prevents the first value in each group from getting filled by the prior group's last value.

Comment: Oh, gosh, I just did some quickie timings expanding this to about 32,000 rows.  It looks like that `apply/lambda` is just murdering the speed here.  Merely re-writing as in my previous comment here will vastly speed it up, as will all 3 answers below.

Comment: @JohnE just confirmed your finding, that's insane!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want speed, avoiding groupby and using numpy instead of pandas are good rules to follow.  That's often not possible, but here you have special case with extremely regular data and all you need is subscript triplet of form `[start:end:stride]`:

```
df.iloc[0::4,1] = df.iloc[1::4,1].values
df.iloc[3::4,1] = df.iloc[2::4,1].values
```

Explanation:  Most people know that you can use subscripts of the form `[start:stop]` but you can also add an optional `stride` argument.  So the first line says to replace elements 0,4,8,... with elements 1,5,9,...  The "values" is necessary to remove pandas indexing which is actually detrimental here.

This ought to be a bit faster just by avoiding groupby.  For a little more speed, you could output column B to numpy, do work in numpy (basically the same code), and then reimport to pandas:

```
arr = df.B.values
arr[0::4] = arr[1::4]  
arr[3::4] = arr[2::4]
df.B = arr
```

Another thing you could do if you wanted to stay in pandas would be to unstack, copy entire columns, then re-stack. That's essentially what the above code is doing anyway.  Honestly with such a rectangular sort of problem any array-style approach is going to be fairly fast.

Comment: This is the fastest solution. @JohnE's other suggestion - to remove the `apply/lambda` also gave a huge speedup. Just for readability I might use that.

Answer (score 3):

If your data really well structured with continuous groups, then you can avoid `groupby` by using the `limit` parameter in `ffill` and `bfill` like:

```
print (df['B'].ffill(limit=1).bfill(limit=1))
0    f1
1    f1
2    b1
3    b1
4    f2
5    f2
6    b2
7    b2
Name: B, dtype: object
```

Comment: Ah, this is definitely the simplest way if you are staying in pandas.  Not sure if it will be faster than numpy (might be tho), but pretty close at worst I'd guess.

Comment: @JohnE I tried with a dataframe build from `pd.concat([df]*1000)` (so 8K rows) and your solution wins easily: `13.3 µs ± 279 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)` for yours, 100x time faster than this one: `1.53 ms ± 76.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)`

Comment: OK, thanks.  I did some quickie timings on 32,000 rows and it was much closer than that (but I did it quickly so who knows).  My iloc version was a little faster and then the numpy version a little faster still (approx 10x compared to yours).  In any event OP has a good range of simple and/or fast to choose from.

Comment: @JohnE I was not surprised that numpy solution is so much faster, but maybe I did a mistake in the timing too, it can be tricky to do sometimes :)

Answer (score 1):

If you format is pre-fix as `(Nan, x, y, Nan)`, when can do

```
df.B=df.groupby([df.A,df.index//2]).B.transform('first')
Out[169]: 
    B
0  f1
1  f1
2  b1
3  b1
4  f2
5  f2
6  b2
7  b2
```