# Automatically fill in the previous value in an excel cell in Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm a beginner in Python. I have some excel issue.

1.I have excel file.

```
    |  Name   | Score | 
    |Alex     |  83.5 | 
    |Annie    |       |
    |Bob      |       |  
    |Lucy     | 243.1 |
    |David    |       |
    |Kate     |       |
    |Cathrine |       |
    |Rose     | 757.5 | 
    |Mary     |       |
    |Johnny   |       |
    |Roy      |       |
```

2. I want to make `Score` auto fill in the empty cell form previous score. Below is my expected result.

   ```
    |  Name   | Score | 
    |Alex     |  83.5 | 
    |Annie    |  83.5 |
    |Bob      |  83.5 |  
    |Lucy     | 243.1 |
    |David    | 243.1 |
    |Kate     | 243.1 |
    |Cathrine | 243.1 |
    |Rose     | 757.5 | 
    |Mary     | 757.5 |
    |Johnny   | 757.5 |
    |Roy      | 757.5 |
   ```
3. But my code is not work. Please teach me how to edit.

   ```
   df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Data.xlsx')
    for i, j in enumerate(df['Score']):
        if j() == '':
           df.at[i,'Score'] = df.at[i-1,'Score']
   ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fillna (forward fill) on a large dataframe efficiently with groupby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36871783/fillna-forward-fill-on-a-large-dataframe-efficiently-with-groupby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
df.ffill(axis = 0)
```

Example

```
import pandas as pd
 
df=pd.DataFrame({"A":[5,3,None,4],
                 "B":[None,2,4,3],
                 "C":[4,3,8,5],
                 "D":[5,4,2,None]})
 
df.ffill(axis=0)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code *and* data as text, not images